# Nginx error while deploying RoR to AWS Beanstalk

Tags: nginx, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to deploy a Ruby on Rails API to AWS Elastic Beanstalk without any luck. I could once deploy succesfully and I'd only got errors because production environment doesn't db:seed. But suddenly every time i wanted to deploy I would have the following errors on logs

```
-------------------------------------
/var/app/support/logs/passenger.log
-------------------------------------
[ 2016-12-16 13:22:39.2849 5408/7f442ea10780 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:728 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
2016/12/16 13:22:40 [error] 5427#0: *3 "/var/app/current/public/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0"
2016/12/16 13:22:40 [error] 5427#0: *3 testing "/var/app/current/public" existence failed (2: No such file or directory) while logging request, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0"


-------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-activity.log
-------------------------------------
  + service passenger restart
   --> Downloading a Phusion Passenger agent binary for your platform
  ---------------------------------------
  No precompiled Nginx engine could be downloaded. Compiling it from source instead.
  --------------------------------------------

  Your system does not have a lot of virtual memory

  Installing...
  Downloading Nginx 1.8.1 source code...
  Extracting tarball...
  Compiling support libraries (step 1 of 2)...
  Compiling Nginx engine (step 2 of 2)...

  ./configure: error: invalid option "--with-http_v2_module"
  *** ERROR: command failed: cd /tmp/passenger-install.158a2iu/nginx-1.8.1 && env PASSENGER_INCLUDEDIR=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.0/src PASSENGER_LIBS=/tmp/passenger-install.158a2iu/common/libpassenger_common/Logging.o\ /tmp/passenger-install.158a2iu/common/libpassenger_common/Exceptions.o\ /tmp/passenger-install.158a2iu/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/SystemTime.o\ /tmp/passenger-install.158a2iu/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/StrIntUtils.o\ /tmp/passenger-install.158a2iu/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/StrIntUtilsNoStrictAliasing.o\ /tmp/passenger-install.158a2iu/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/IOUtils.o\ /tmp/passenger-install.158a2iu/common/libpassenger_common/Utils.o\ /tmp/passenger-install.158a2iu/common/libpassenger_common/WatchdogLauncher.o\ /tmp/passenger-install.158a2iu/common/libpassenger_common/AppTypes.o\ /tmp/passenger-install.158a2iu/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/CachedFileStat.o\ /tmp/passenger-install.158a2iu/common/libpassenger_common/UnionStationFilterSupport.o\ /tmp/passenger-install.158a2iu/common/libboost_oxt.a /bin/bash ./configure --prefix=/tmp --with-cc-opt=-Wno-error --without-http_fastcgi_module --without-http_scgi_module --without-http_uwsgi_module --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_addition_module --add-module=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.0/src/nginx_module
```

I even git revert commits in order to go back to the version that deployed succesfully but got the same errors!

PD:
Another thing I had to do (before it worked the first time) was set the Root volume size of the EC2 instance to 16 GiB because i would get the error that nokogiri gem couldn't be installed by budler, and it actually fixed that

Comment: Why are you using version 1.8.1 of nginx? That was released nearly a year ago, and is listed as a "legacy" version on nginx's downloads page...

Also, if you want to run `db:seed` on deploy, create a file under `.ebextensions` and use a container_commands directive to do so. More details can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371615/how-do-you-call-dbseed-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-apps

Comment: @lucas-rodriguez  Have you been able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The error you are seeing is almost probably because you have `Passenger` Gem listed in the Gemfile. Removing it or putting it into the `development` section if needed should solve the issue.
`Passenger` is pre-installed on the AWS ElasticBeanstalk Ruby Stack.

Comment: I'm running into the exact same issue and did in fact have `Passenger` in the Gemfile.  However, the error persists after removing it.  When this app was previously configured on DigitalOcean, it had to be restarted manually by running `touch tmp/restart.txt`.  Do you think I need to do something of the sort here?

Comment: If you haven't done so I would try to rebuild the ElasticBeanstalk environment. This can be done via AWS console.

Comment: Yup!  After I'd removed `Passenger`, restarting the project in a fresh environment did the trick.  Must've somehow permanently borked it.